# Angular2 - subscribe not triggering service call

Tags: angular

I have a component that is subscribing to an observable in a service. But the subscribe doesn't trigger the get within the service.  Here is my service....

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { IMeasureRating } from './measureRating';
    import { IRating } from './rating';
    import { IMeasure } from './measure';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    import { ErrorHandler } from '../error-handler/error-handler.component';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


    declare function require(name: string);

    @Injectable(
    )

export class MeasureRatingService{
    private _ratingURL = 'http://localhost:54255/api/MeasureRating/';

    errorMessage: string = '';

    constructor(private _http: Http, private _errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {
    }    
        getMeasureNames(): Observable<IMeasure[]> {

            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

            return this._http.get(this._ratingURL + "getMeasureNames", { headers: headers })
                .map((response: Response) => <IMeasure[]>response.json())
                .do(data => console.log("MR getMeasureNames: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
                .catch(this.handleError)
        }
```

And here is the component code that is trying to make use of it...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'measureRatings',
    template: require('./measureRating.component.html')
})
.
.
.
export class measureRatingComponent implements OnInit {
.
.
.
    constructor(private _MRService: MeasureRatingService, private _router: Router) {

    }

.
.

    buildDefaults()
    {
        this.defaultMeasureNames = [];
        this._MRService.getMeasureNames()
            .subscribe(x => this.defaultMeasureNames = x,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => { this.buildDefaultRatingArray() });
    }
```

I am pretty sure there is only one instance of the service running. The only place that it appears is in the Providers section of the component module. BuildDefaults() is being called from ngOnChanges of the component. Any thoughts?

thanks in advance.

Comment: call BuildDefaults() from ngOnInit , becuase ngOnChanges is called when some data-bound property of the component changes

Answer (score 0):

You have not use "return" to return the response of response.json() in service. 
Also add providers class of your service in component.

Try to use below code snippet.

> Service.ts

```
@Injectable()

export class MeasureRatingService{
  private _ratingURL = 'http://localhost:54255/api/MeasureRating/';
  errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp, private _http: Http, 
              private _errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {
  }    

  getMeasureNames(): Observable<IMeasure[]> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.get(this._ratingURL + "getMeasureNames", options)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                  return <IMeasure[]>response.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || ' error');
    }
}
```

> component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Service } from '../shared/services/service';

@Component({
    selector: 'measureRatings',
    template: require('./measureRating.component.html'),
    providers: [Service]
})

export class measureRatingComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _MRService: MeasureRatingService, 
                private _router: Router) {
    }

.
.

    buildDefaults()
    {
        this.defaultMeasureNames = [];
        this._MRService.getMeasureNames()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                   this.defaultMeasureNames = data;
             },                 
            error => {this.errorMessage = <any>error},
            () => { this.buildDefaultRatingArray() }
            );
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: sorry, that didnt work.  I have a module that sets up the service so i don't need to put the provider in the component.